# JetBrains Rider debug mode evaluator exception

Tags: .net, ide, jetbrains-ide, rider, jetbrains-rider

I am struggling with Rider on my MacBook as I am unable to evaluate IEnumerables while debugging my code. I am currently running Rider 2021.3.1, but the issue has persisted since before Rider 2021.2. As I do not want to use `ToList()` all over, this issue makes it a lot harder to debug as I am unable to verify values and count from my enumerables. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

When I first encountered the issue I had set my `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` to `Release`, however I have not set it back to `Development`, and I am running it in debug mode in Rider.

[image]

Comment: Please submit a bug report to JetBrains with Help - Report a Bu, agree to attach logs. Do it right after reproducing the issue, so logs would have the info.

Comment: @IvanShakhov: The issue link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RIDER-75248/evaluator-exception-in-F

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. Close Rider
2. Delete or rename `.idea` directory from your solution folder
3. Start Rider.

This solved the issue for me.

If you want, you can try deleting `workspace.xml` file inside the subdirectory of .idea directory. Only *significant* difference between the new directory content vs old is, `workspace.xml`. So you can just delete/rename it and give a try.

Comment: Thank you, this did the trick for me as well

Comment: I finally got frustrated enough to look this issue up, and found this answer. This was a lifesaver, thank you!

Comment: The deleting of just workspace.xml helped me

Comment: If you don't want to lose the entire `workspace.xml` try removing `<component name="DisabledMethodsStorage">` entry in the workspace.xml. That fixed it for me. It had an entry to disable `System.Linq.SystemCore_EnumerableDebugView`. Not sure why.